# Encapsulate interface implementation of property

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, properties, encapsulation

I have an `Object` class that allows objects to be linked together.

A -> B -> C (one way linking)

When a link is formed between two objects by calling `Link(IObject other)`, I want to set `IsReferenced` on the `Next` object.

So in the above example, A references B, but B does not reference A, B just has it's `IsReferenced` property set to true.

However, I only want the `IsReferenced` setter to be available to classes that implement the `IObject` interface. i.e the `IsReferenced` should only be able to be set inside the `Object` class, outside code should not be able to set it.

However, the code fails to compile as `IsReferenced` when accessed via the interface is read only.

```
 public interface IObject
{
    bool IsReferenced { get; }
    IObject? Next { get; }
    void Link(IObject next);
}

public class Object : IObject
{
    public bool IsReferenced { get; }
    public IObject? Next { get; private set; }

    public void Link(IObject next)
    {
        Next = next;
        next.IsReferenced = true;
    }
}
```

I can resolve the issue by doing the following :

```
public void Link(IObject next)
{
    Next = next;
    ((Object)next).IsReferenced = true;
}
```

But this won't work for my scenario, as I need to be able to `Mock<IObject>`

Is there a better solution other than making the `IsReferenced` a public setter?

Comment: Can you do `other.Link(this)`?

Comment: How is the actual Link represented? Other than setting a bool, I don't see the link after the method has executed. If you do that, I'd actually derive the value of the `IsReferenced` property off of that link reference existing or not.

Comment: No, wait, that will create an infinite loop... Maybe only perform the logic inside `Link()` if `!IsReferenced`

Comment: @AstridE its a one way link. A->B->C

Comment: _"its a one way link."_ - No it's not. As is, it is no link at all. You cannot traverse. As is, you wouldn't even know if the current Object is the source or the target of a "link".

Comment: use abstraction instead of interface

Comment: @Fildor I have updated the description to better explain my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Is using a helper method to 'activate' `IsReferenced` an option for you?

By calling a helper method on the linked object with the object that has just linked it, the linked object can itself verify that it has in fact been referenced.

Here is a suggestion where `OnLinkedBy()` is the helper method:

```
public interface IObject
{
    bool IsReferenced { get; }
    IObject? Next { get; }
    void Link(IObject next);
    void OnLinkedBy(IObject other);
}

public class Object : IObject
{
    private IObject? _next { get; set; }

    public bool IsReferenced { get;  private set; }
    
    public IObject? Next
    {
        get => _next;
        private set
        {
            _next = value;
            
            if (_next is not null)
            {
                _next.OnLinkedBy(this);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void Link(IObject next) => Next = next;
    
    public void OnLinkedBy(IObject other)
    {
        if (other.Next == this)
        {
            IsReferenced = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if you do

```
var objectA = new Object();
var objectB = new Object();

objectA.Link(objectB);

Console.WriteLine("ObjectA is linked: " + (objectA.Next != null));
Console.WriteLine("ObjectA is referenced: " + objectA.IsReferenced);
Console.WriteLine("ObjectB is linked: " + (objectB.Next != null));
Console.WriteLine("ObjectB is referenced: " + objectB.IsReferenced);
```

the output will be:

> ObjectA is linked: True
> ObjectA is referenced: False
> ObjectB is linked: False
> ObjectB is referenced: True

---

Note: If you also want to be able to *dereference*, this simple approach will not cover your need.

Comment: This is no different to just having IsReferenced be a public setter. The point is that IsReferenced should be maintained by the class implementing IObject, and should not be publicly available for anyone to change it.

Comment: @wforl I do not agree that it was 'no different', as no outside object could set `IsReferenced` to `false`. But I do understand it was not what you were looking for. I have updated my answer and replaced the original helper method with a helper method that takes an object as an input parameter, so that the linked object can verify on its own that it has in fact been linked. I believe it is closer to something you could accept using, although perhaps not exactly what you are aiming for.

Comment: Thanks but it's a bit convoluted and exposes a new method on the interface that really doesn't belong,  but I guess there is no clean way.

Comment: Good points. I could not find a cleaner way myself, but am eager to see if someone posts an elegant approach.